# Keepalive for website that automatically logs you out too quickly

Tags: firefox

There's a site I requent that automatically logs you out after a few minutes of inactivity. Due to the way I use it I don't interact for long times because I'm reading its lengthy text.

I need some kind of keepalive. What works well with Firefox?

I tried [Session Keepalive](https://addons.mozilla.org/EN-us/firefox/addon/session-keep-alive/) and it didn't work.

Comment: A relatively foolish solution could be running a repetitive JS script that makes ajax requests to the server and keeps your session fresh! `:)`

Comment: This sounds to me like a simple auto-reload-feature. I am also keeping a website loaded on which I would be thrown out after some time. So I simply set up the automatic reload functionality (of my Tab Utilities Fixed in this old Firefox) for the tab every few minutes.
Such a simple functionality should be included in many add-ons and Firefox should also not having a problem with keeping the current reading position on the site.